# Linux: Slow browsers when using http proxy

Tags: linux, http-proxy

Thanks for reading this.

So basically there's a http proxy I'm trying to use.
Proxy performance is pretty good, things like `curl` or `apt` work really fast.

However, when I try to use the same proxy with chrome/firefox - both browsers work extremely slow.

Opening `google.com` literally takes around a minute. It does not seem to be network related since opening sites with curl is still fast. Browsers just seem to hang for some reason

Would really appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 3rd party http proxy, then it is expected.

curl and apt are text and the end servers does not look for the country or city of origin. Plus the proxy provider does not need to NAT the traffic.

With media though, the end server will check for country of origin and will also try to use cookies. Manging cookies and NAT-ing the traffic adds an over head to your traffic/request.

If you really want a the use of a http proxy to view media or news from other countries, I suggest using an internation VPN provider.

Comment: Media, are you covering pictures as well as videos in your answer?